# Qt application startup crash

Tags: c++, linux, qt, crash, x86-64

I'm doing a larger - still small - game project as homework. It is based on Qt 4.8.6, and runs perfectly on Windows 7 64 bit. It also compiles on 64 bit Linux, but crashes at startup. The point of crash seems quite common with different stack traces, but I did not find my case on the net and I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried

- Recompiled the project. Recompiled Qt.
- Searched the web. Again. Again.
- Walked up and down in gdb (will recompile qt with debug symbols)
- Watched it with strace, last movement is loading of `/usr/lib/libicudata.so.44`

gdb backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000ecf720 in QResourceRoot::operator==(QResourceRoot const&) const ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000ecf720 in QResourceRoot::operator==(QResourceRoot const&) const ()
#1  0x0000000000ecd175 in qRegisterResourceData (version=1, tree=0x10d8f60 "", name=0x10d8ee0 "", data=0x10d8320 "") at io/qresource.cpp:846
#2  0x0000000000bda227 in qInitResources_qmessagebox () at .rcc/debug-static/qrc_qmessagebox.cpp:257
#3  0x0000000000bda27a in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at .rcc/debug-static/qrc_qmessagebox.cpp:261
#4  0x0000000000bda2be in global constructors keyed to qrc_qmessagebox.cpp () at .rcc/debug-static/qrc_qmessagebox.cpp:270
#5  0x0000000000fee3e6 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#6  0x000000000040ee1b in _init ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

( Original when Qt were not with "-debug": http://pastebin.com/6GsKDM8d )

- `Application: public QApplication`
- Constructor does nothing, just passes `argc`, `argv` onwards.
- I don't have global `Q` things. I don't have global things in general, just some simple constants.

Program compilation (examples per kind):

- uic: `uic inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.ui -o inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.ui.h`
- moc: `moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../thirdparty/qt/include inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.h -o inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.moc.cpp`
- cxx: `g++ -DDEBUG -g -o inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.moc.o -c -fmessage-length=0 -fpermissive -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -MMD -MP -MF"inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.moc.d" -MT"inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.moc.d" -Iinc/ed -I../utils/inc/ed -I../ejson/inc/ed -I../thirdparty/boost -I../thirdparty/qt/include -c inc/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.moc.cpp`
- cxx: `g++ -DDEBUG -g -o src/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.o -c -fmessage-length=0 -fpermissive -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -MMD -MP -MF"src/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.d" -MT"src/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.d" -Iinc/ed -I../utils/inc/ed -I../ejson/inc/ed -I../thirdparty/boost -I../thirdparty/qt/include -c src/ed/gomoku/ui/FEditProfile.cpp`
- link: `g++ -DDEBUG -g -o gomoku_client  gomoku_client.a ../ejson/ejson.a ../utils/utils.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a ../thirdparty/boost/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a ../thirdparty/qt/lib_lin64/libQtGui.a ../thirdparty/qt/lib_lin64/libQtCore.a -lpthread -lz -ldl -lX11 -lXft -lXext -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lSM`

ldd output:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff91fff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f51ce520000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f51ce309000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f51ce104000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f51cddc9000)
    libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f51cdbb5000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f51cd9a2000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f51cd6c6000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f51cd4c2000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f51cd27a000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f51cd072000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f51ccd5e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f51ccadb000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f51cc8c5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f51cc563000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f51ce75c000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f51cc32d000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f51cc0a5000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f51cbe9b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f51cbc92000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f51cba77000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f51cb85b000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f51cb62a000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f51cb426000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f51cb1fd000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f51caffa000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f51cadf5000)
```

Qt configure: `./configure -prefix ~/local/qt -opensource -confirm-license -static -no-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -no-xmlpatterns -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-svg -no-webkit -no-javascript-jit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-declarative -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libtiff -qt-libmng -qt-libjpeg -no-openssl -nomake demos -nomake examples -no-nis -no-cups -no-iconv -no-dbus -no-opengl`

/proc/version: `Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze4) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 22:14:43 UTC 2013`

Comment: What is at Application.cpp:25 and main.cpp:49?

Comment: @SebastianLange `Application a(argc,argv);`, `Application::Application(int& argc, char ** argv): QApplication(argc, argv) { }` The latter is a bit odd (int reference), but should not be a problem. Will fix and see.

Comment: I have different stack-trace after compiling with `-debug`. A lot shorter. Adding as link.

Comment: the intref is ok. This should not crash at all, its a valid implementation.

Comment: Meeeh. Recompiling everything and recopying the include files helped. That last step was crucial. Thanks for the efforts @SebastianLange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misterious crashes can happen if the qt `include` directory we use is not exactly for the library (`.lib`, `.a`) we use. The application may compile and link without any warnings, but unexpected crashes may easily arise.

Comment: The crashes are rather expected when you mix binary-incompatible versions of Qt :)

Comment: @KubaOber I had 4.8.6 for Windows and for Linux. Different headers are generated when building it. I have only seen libraries that make distinctions amongst platforms with `#ifdef`s. Now I know that's not the case.

Comment: An installed version of Qt is a self-contained unit, for a particular architecture. You'll run into endless trouble if you try to use it otherwise.